# How can I install my Xbox 360 wired controller?

Tags: 10.04, configuration, xbox-360

I have tried the install instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xbox360Controller but I keep getting an error message at the point when I'm executing the Make file.

```
warlord@warlord-laptop:~/xpad$ make
make modules -C /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-32-generic SUBDIRS=/home/warlord/xpad
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-32-generic'
   CC [M]  /home/warlord/xpad/xpad.o
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c: In function ‘xpad_wireless_connect’:
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c:291: error: implicit declaration of function ‘info’
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c: In function ‘xpad_open’:
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c:382: error: ‘struct input_dev’ has no member named ‘private’
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c: In function ‘xpad_close’:
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c:408: error: ‘struct input_dev’ has no member named ‘private’
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c: In function ‘xpad_probe’:
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c:496: error: ‘struct input_dev’ has no member named ‘cdev’
/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.c:497: error: ‘struct input_dev’ has no member named ‘private’
make[2]: *** [/home/warlord/xpad/xpad.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/warlord/xpad] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-32-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why is this happening? I've also tried xboxdrv, and the jscalibrator is no longer supported in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. And i also used `lsinput` and it shows my gamepad correctly in event 10 but not in js0 or js1.

```
/dev/input/event10
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x45e
   product : 0x28e
   version : 276
   name    : "Microsoft X-Box 360 pad"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:1d.2-1/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS EV_FF
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not necessary to install the controller in 10.04. it should just work, though not for games running wine that use the xinput interface i.e. many newer titles

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can atm as the wireless Xbox 360 controller uses different protocols to standard bluetooth ones – and i don't think the protocol is out in the open yet either.

The USB based ones should work, however. From what i heaar, you don't need to compile drivers - it works out of the box. Have you tried it with any games?

Comment: Sorry for the bad grammar :)

Comment: the question is asking about the installation of a wired (USB) controller.

Comment: the controller i have is a wired. not wireless. I tried many different things to get it to work. is it an issue in the Make file shown in ubuntu [link]( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xbox360Controller). If so how should I change it to work ??? I am new to Linux terminal.